# How to implement apple watch crown delegate using objective c

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch

I am working on apple watch application where i need to use crown to update label value .I have achieved the functionality using swift. In swift we have property named crownSequencer to implement crown delegate like
 `crownSequencer.delegate=self; crownSequencer.focus();`
but I am unable to fined a way to implement it in objective c, because  objective c does not show any property named `crownSequencer`
 any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CrownSequence can be accessible via InterfaceController object.

In Objective C it can be accessed by this way :

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    // Configure interface objects here.
    self.crownSequencer.delegate = self;
}
- (void)willActivate {
   [super willActivate];
   [self.crownSequencer focus];
}
```

NOTE ::[self.crownSequencer focus] should not be call within (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context otherwise delegate method will not be call

Here you can find more info

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer?language=objc